# minimum value of $a+b+c$ is

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ such
>
> that $f(x)=0$ has $3$ distinct integral roots
>
> and $f(g(x))=0$ does not have real roots,
>
> where $g(x)=x^2+2x-5.$ Then minimum
>
> value of $a+b+c$ is

what i try

for $f(g(x))=(x^2+2x-5)^3+a(x^2+2x-5)^2+b(x^2+2x-5)+c$

$x^2+2x-5=(x+1)^2-6$

$f(g(x))=\bigg((x+1)^2-6\bigg)^3+a\bigg((x+1)^2-6\bigg)^2+b\bigg((x+1)^2-6\bigg)+c$

Howq do isolve it Help me please

Comment: We have that $g(x)\ge-6$ and hence all roots of $f(x)=0$ are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\le-7$. Then use the fact that $a+b+c=f(1)-1=(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)(1-\gamma)-1$ to minimise $a+b+c$. Which gives a minimum value of $8^3-1=511$.

Comment: i did not understand why $f(x)=0$ has roots $\leq -7,$ please explain me in detail @peter Foreman

Comment: Since $g(x)\ge-6$ all of the values of $f(x)$ where $x\ge-6$ do not produce real roots from the second fact.

Comment: I didn't read "distinct integral roots". You should get $(a+b+c)_{\text{min}}=8\cdot9\cdot10-1=719$.

Comment: Thanks Peter foreman got it.